# Change my version for an Cordova iOS App

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have an app that appears to be version 0.0.1 when in the Organiser screen but the existing app is version 1.0 in the App Store - I basically want to set this version number to be 1.1 (so it differentiates from any other versions and doesn't overwrite)

Where do I change this in Xcode or directly in the code itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is derived from the `version` attribute of the `widget` element in `config.xml` (the one in the project root folder).

You'll have to run `cordova prepare ios` after changing the `config.xml` to update the project.

(You could change it in Xcode directly - there is a file ending on `-Info.plist`, but this change would be overwritten every time the project is generated.)

Comment: reminder, be carefull when running cordova prepare ios, it will copy the root www files to platform/ios. People working dirrectly in xcode often loose all their work when running this command!

Comment: It's strange how it updates both `Version` and `Build` in Xcode with whatever you give the version attr in config.xml. `Build` is conventionally not a semantic version string.